# Seeking an analytic solution to a first order nonlinear ordinary differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Does anyone have suggestions on how to tackle the following equation:

$$\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)^2 = B(\sin(y(x)))^2 - C\sin(y(x)) + D $$

The constants are real and nonzero

Comment: A start: write the RHS as $(A\sin(y) - K)^2$ for constants $A$ and $K$

Comment: with that: $(y')^2=(A\sin(y)-K)^2$ implies $y'=A\sin(y)-K$ is  your simplified equation.

Comment: @Tim What if it's not a perfect square?

Comment: Is there a way to exploit the lack of $x$ in the equation?

Comment: I'm not sure it can be treated as a perfect square. The constants are quite involved. B=(2K/C) C=(2MB/C) and D=(M^2B^2)/2KC. The "C" as a constant is not the same as the C in the denominator of the fractions, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: As ugly as it is, you could square root both sides to yield a separable equation.

Comment: It does work as a perfect square! That vastly simplifies the problem, great suggestion!

Comment: The direct separable method requires some ingenious trig substitutions that I have not found yet, if you come up with one that works please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

There are closed-form constant solutions (which may or may not be real, depending on the values of the parameters).  Otherwise, you need to integrate

$$  \int \dfrac{dy}{\sqrt{B \sin^2(y) - C \sin(y) + D}} $$

which seems not to be elementary in general: Maple gives a rather complicated antiderivative
in terms of EllipticF, which is the incomplete elliptic integral of the first kind.